# Insert into second row of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert values to second row of table. First row of table has value and it’s constant. The “total” in each row is ((Total from previous row + Entry)-Exit).

But it doesn’t calculate first row(Constant) in total.

My code is:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable([MDate], [MEntry], [MExit], [MTotal])
    SELECT 
        EDate, SUM(count1) EntryC, SUM(count2) ExitC, 
        SUM(SUM(count1) - SUM(count2)) OVER (ORDER BY EDate) Total1
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             SUBSTRING(EntryDate, 1, 4) EDate, 
             COUNT(*) count1, 0 count2, 0t
         FROM 
             [dbo].[Dash]
         WHERE
             SUBSTRING(EntryDate, 1, 4) > 2010
         GROUP BY 
             SUBSTRING(EntryDate, 1, 4)

         UNION

         SELECT  
             SUBSTRING(CntEndDate, 1, 4) EDate, 0 count1,
             COUNT(*) count2, 0t
         FROM 
             [dbo].[Dash]
         WHERE  
             PostNo <> 0 AND EmpTypeNo = 7 
         GROUP BY 
             SUBSTRING(CntEndDate, 1, 4)) A 
    GROUP BY 
        EDate
```

My output is:

```
MDate  MEntry  MExit  Total
----------------------------
2010    110     107    549
2011    80      41     850
```

Total=850 is wrong, it should be 588.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "second row" of a table.

Comment: I must admit, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve in your query. You say you want to add one row to your tables, but you select many. Some by date, some by other criteria, then removing duplicates with `UNION`. By mistake? Be careful with data types. I suppose that `EntryDate` and `CntEndDate` are dates? Why then do you apply a *string* function (`SUBSTRING`) on them? And if you extract a substring, why do you compare it with a *number* (2010)? And as to the task itself: why do you want to store the cumulative sums redundantly in a table, when you can always get them ad hoc?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner:   The table already has a record and it shouldn't change.  I want to insert lot's of records exactly after this record(Constant). so, in this situation, "Total"  is not calculated correctly.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner our date stores in string format in DB because of some reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on hour description, the calculation for the total should look like:

```
select mdate, mentry, mexit,
       (max(case when seqnum = 1 then total else 0 end) over (order by mdate) +
        sum(case when seqnum > 1 then mentry - mexit else 0 end) over (order by mdate)
       ) as new_total
from (select d.*, row_number() over (order by mdate) as seqnum
      from dash d
     ) d
```

I'm not quite sure how that fits in with the rest oft he question, though.